# jQuery does not recognize Euro symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with euro symbol. Suppose a value like 20€ Now i want to extract the value to get 20. But jQuery can't recognize € symbol. Please anyone help me out.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not with jQuery (which doesn't really care what characters you use, but somewhere else).  Here is proof ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SeKV4/)):

```
<input id='input' value='20€'/><button id='getVal'>Extract</button>

<script>
  $('#getVal').on('click', function() {
    alert($('#input').val().split('€')[0]);
  })
</script>
```

Comment: `val().replace("€", "")`

Comment: True :) or a regex looking for only digits (though that might have issues with decimals or negative values).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#your-element').val().replace(/\u20ac/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this with a parseInt of the input value. Try this:

```
var price = document.getElementById('input').value;
var number = parseInt(price, 10);
alert(number);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because the sign of euro in HTML has escape caracters & euro; so you end up having something like 20 & euro; and not 20 €.  I just copied the character itself and placed it where i wanted and worked. 
So instead of

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(
                function(){
                        $("#creditlbl").text("20 &euro;").html();
                }
        );
</script>
```

I wrote

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(
                function(){
                        $("#creditlbl").text("20 €").html();
                }
        );
</script>
```